# How can I determine the parameters that were bound in just the current pipeline step?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

Consider the following script:

```
function g
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$x,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$y,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$z
    )
    process
    {
        $retval = @{psbp=@{};mibp=@{};x=$x;y=$y;z=$z}
        $PSBoundParameters.Keys |
            % { $retval.psbp.$_ = $PSBoundParameters.$_ }
        $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Keys |
            % { $retval.mibp.$_ = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.$_} 
        return New-Object psobject -Property $retval
    }
}

$list = (New-Object psobject -Property @{x=1;z=3}),
        (New-Object psobject -Property @{x=$null;y=2} ) 
$list | 
    g |
    Select bp,x,y,z |
    ft -AutoSize
```

Running the script results in the following output:

```
psbp      mibp      x y z
----      ----      - - -
{z, x}    {z, x}    1   3
{y, z, x} {y, z, x}   2
```

This seems to reveal that both `$PSBoundParameters` and `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters` contain the *cumulation* of all the parameters bound so far.

I'm fairly sure that `$x` and `$z` were bound on the first step, and `$x` and `$y` were bound on the second step, but I haven't found a way to retrieve that detail programmatically.

How can I determine the parameters that were bound in just the current pipeline step?

---

Why do I care about this?  Some kinds of parameter validation are more complex than can be achieved using language features like parameter sets, `ValidateScript()`, etc.  That validation has to be performed inside the function body.  Occasionally it is desirable to consider an unbound parameter to be semantically different from passing `$null` to that same parameter.  Detection of bound parameters is customarily achieved by interrogating `$PSBoundParameters`.  This works fine if you pass only a single parameter object on the pipeline.  However, if you pipe a list of parameter objects using the pipeline, that detection is foiled because of the problem demonstrated by the script above.  This is violates the principle-of-least surprise because a function that worked fine inside a `foreach` loop behaves dramatically differently when the caller happens to invoke it by piping those same objects to it.

I *can* work around this by calling the affected functions from within a `foreach`, but I'd rather solve the problem for all invocations rather than abandon the pipeline altogether.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question. What's your ultimate goal? Also try using `Trace-Command` and see if it maybe reveals anything about the binding process.

Comment: @briantist I added an explanation to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remember all parameters bounded by command line in `begin` block, then in the end of `process` block you can clean up `$PSBoundParameters` from parameters bounded by current input object:

```
function g
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$x,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$y,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]$z
    )
    begin
    {
        $CommandLineBoundParameters=@($PSBoundParameters.Keys)
    }
    process
    {
        ...

        @($PSBoundParameters.Keys) |
            ? { $CommandLineBoundParameters -notcontains $_ } |
            % { [void]$PSBoundParameters.Remove($_) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it will work.  I put some formal CI tests [here](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/blob/2790e93d502cd92c4217c22cbf1fb1cc140836f6/EnvironmentTests/parameterBinding.Tests.ps1#L412-L471).  Those tests pass under PowerShell 2, 4 and 5.  Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Nice Pester tests @alx9r !

Comment: :) Thanks @briantist.